# Shortcut Win+arrow Kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I am a new user in kali.
In windows I can do Win + arrow which move the current window to the left or to the right of my screen. Unfortunately with kali the win key just bring the search bar.
I tried many things, with xbindkeys to add :

```
xdotool windowsize $(xdotool getwindowfocus) 50% 100% && xdotool windowmove $(xdotool getwindowfocus) 0 y
```

but that doesn't work.
However, when I type this command in my terminal it is working perfectly fine.

I am therefore looking for a way of adding the shortcut win key + left or right arrow to move my window where I want like in Windows.
I would like that way to be persistent to reboot

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am guessing that you are new to Gnu/Linux (not just to kari). Kali is for experts and is unforgiving. Almost everything that can be done in kari can be done in other Gnu/Linux distros. Therefore I recommend a different one (at least for now).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question ! It is perfectly the answer I was looking for ! You will have my eternal gratitude

Comment: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/44425)

Answer (score 0):

Gnu/Linux has a choice of Window-managers (and Desktop environments)

Changing the Window manager is like changing MS-Windows version, but without having to logout, or close any apps.

I don't know which Window manager kali uses (probably a simple, low resource one). I do know that many Window managers support what you are trying to do.

I am using KDE Plasma (Window Manager and Desktop Environment). It supports what you are trying to do (as do others). KDE Plasma also supports everything else that I have seen the MS-Windows system do, and more (Changing the screen split, needed a plugin. The plugin does a little more than MS).